# Static Property fire after Method fired

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms

I am making a small project today to understand xamarin.forms. In my project I have a class named ***CustomerService*** to handle customer logic.  In this class I call a class named ***CustomerDatabase*** that connect to database and manipulate the customers.

```
 public class CustomerServices
{
    static  CustomerDatabase customerDatabase;
    public CustomerServices()
    {

    }


    public  static CustomerDatabase CustomerDatabase
    {
        get
        {
            if(customerDatabase == null)
            {
                customerDatabase = new CustomerDatabase(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "Customer.db3"));
            }
            return customerDatabase;
        }
    }

    public async Task<List<Customer>> GetCustomers()
    {
        return await customerDatabase.GetCustomerAsync();
    }

 }
```

The problem here is the ***GetCustomers()*** method is firing before the static ***CustomerDatabase*** property and because of this I get error about ***customerDatabase*** field is null.

I was expecting because of ***CustomerDatabase*** property static it will fire before all other unstatic methods.

- What is the point I am missing here ?
- Why static property fire after the methods ?

Answer (score 2):

Just like instance properties, static properties are also only syntactic sugar for *static* get and set methods. So they are not "initialized" like static fields.

You don't *call* these methods, since you don't access your property `CustomerDatabase`. So the code is never executed and the *field* `customerDatabase` is not initialized.

You could avoid this by using the *property* `CustomerDatabase` inside the `GetCustomers` method instead of the *field*. But I don't know if that fits with your overall approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
     public class CustomerServices {

        public static CustomerDatabase CustomerDatabase
        {
                get
                {  
                    return value ??  new CustomerDatabase(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
                }
        }

        public async Task<List<Customer>> GetCustomers()
        {
            return await CustomerDatabase.GetCustomerAsync();
        }

     }
```